# Site de ver velocidade da internet

Tags: ping

Quais linguagens são usadas pra criar esses sites de velocidade da internet? Poderiam dar exemplos de como calcular isso? Ou é algo complexo?

Comment: Ao pergunta "Quais linguagens são usadas" torna a pergunta muito ampla, pois seria praticamente impossível citar todas que são possíveis, por isso algumas pessoas pode dar o `-1`. Se retirasse isso da pergunta, iria receber mais `+1`, pois é seria interessante saber como funciona, independente de linguagem.

Comment: Entendi, é por que não sei quais. Por isso perguntei. As vezes só tem como com PHP, as vezes com JavaScript, as vezes com mais alguma, mas obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A conta é simples, e qualquer linguagem serve para implementá-la no servidor (no lado do navegador, obviamente tem que ser em *javascript*). Essencialmente você tem que ter um ou vários arquivos de tamanho conhecido, e mandar o navegador do cliente baixar estes arquivos, guardando numa variável o horário do servidor imediatamente antes de começar o *download* e imediatamente após ele terminar.

Subtraindo as duas datas, você tem quanto tempo demorou para o cliente baixar o arquivo, e como  o tamanho do arquivo é conhecido, você divide esse tamanho pelo tempo decorrido e acha a velocidade.

Por exemplo, podemos escrever um arquivo `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Teste de velocidade</title>
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (evt) {
                document.getElementById("executar").addEventListener (evt) {
                    var tam = parseInt(document.getElementById("tam"), 10);
                    var inicio = new Date();
                    fetch("dados.cgi?tam=" + tam, { method: "get" }).then(function (dados) {
                        var fim = new Date();
                        var segundos = (fim.getTime() - inicio.getTime()) / 1000;
                        document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = (tam / segundos) + " B/s";
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Teste de velocidade caseiro</h1>
        <h2>Sua velocidade ao baixar um arquivo de <input type="text" id="tam" value="1048576"> é: <span id="resultado"></span></h2>
        <button id="executar">Testar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

E o `dados.cgi`, escrito em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char * qstring = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    size_t tamanho = 0;

    if (!strncmp(qstring, "tam=", 4)) {
        tamanho = strtoul(qstring + 4, &qstring, 10);
        printf("200 Ok\r\n"
               "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
               "Content-Size: %d\r\n"
               "\r\n",
               tamanho
        );
        fwrite("U", 1, tamanho, stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note que não garanto que esse exemplo funcione, porque não tenho acesso a um servidor para tentar executar o script CGI, mas não vai diferir muito disso. Neste caso, criei um CGI para gerar arquivos na hora com um tamanho arbitrário, mas você poderia ter um conjunto de arquivos estáticos no seu servidor para baixar. Também falta qualquer tipo de verificação de erro neste script (por exemplo, se puser um valor não numérico ou zero na caixa de tamanho, o script dá pau). Mas como uma ideia geral, deve servir.

Comment: Obrigado, vou pesquisar como fazer isso "Essencialmente você tem que ter um ou vários arquivos de tamanho conhecido, e mandar o navegador do cliente baixar estes arquivos".

Comment: Não entendo o down vote do pessoal, de verdade.